# OpenCL2.0 kernel giving access violation error at clBuildProgram

Tags: opencl, amd-gpu

I have written a simple kernel, which uses new feature of OpenCL 2.0 clang blocks.

```
int multiplier = 7;

__kernel void clang_blocks_ocl(__global int* input_array, __global int* output_array)

{
    int global_id = get_global_id(0);   
    int ^MultiplayByConstant(int) = ^int (int num) {return multiplier*num;} ;
    output_array[global_id] = MultiplayByConstant(input_array[global_id]);
    
}
```

I am passing each element of input array to block and getting it multiplied by some constant as you see that in code.

This is my configuration.

- OS : Win7 64bit
- Graphics Card : AMD
- Driver Version : Crimson 15.30

As per debugging the application is hanging at `clBuildProgram` and application is getting crashed without any return code. I have passed all correct arguments to `clBuildProgram` including compile option `"-cl-std=CL2.0"`.

Comment: Can you post a minimal and complete host code?

Comment: I am posting code for clBuildProgram and as other code works for other kernels without any error.
// setup opencl environment
// create context, command queue
// read kernel source and load it into cl_program
ecode = clBuildProgram(program, 1, Device, "-cl-std=CL2.0",NULL, NULL);

Application giving access violation at this point. Application getting terminated without returning any error code.

Answer (score 0):

Clang blocks were introduced to OpenCL 2.0 for device side enqueue feature, they can't be used for other cases as you are trying to do.

If you meant to use device side enqueue then you need to create device side queue on the host and also modify your kernel - see [AMD tutorial](http://developer.amd.com/community/blog/2014/11/17/opencl-2-0-device-enqueue/).

Comment: Yes. You are correct that is one of the use of clang blocks.
I am referring following specification : 
https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/blocks.html